# C++ primer 5th edition ch 19 Bitfieds

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I have this example from C++ primer 5th edition. ch-19 Bit fields:

```
 typedef unsigned int Bit;
 class File {
     Bit mode: 2;       // mode has 2 bits
     Bit modified: 1;   // modified has 1 bit
     Bit prot_owner: 3; // prot_owner has 3 bits
     Bit prot_group: 3; // prot_group has 3 bits
     Bit prot_world: 3; // prot_world has 3 bits
     // operations and data members of File
 public:
     // file modes specified as octal literals; see § 2.1.3 (p. 38)
     enum modes { READ = 01, WRITE = 02, EXECUTE = 03 };
     File &open(modes);
     void close();
     void write();
     bool isRead() const;
     void setWrite();C++ Primer, Fifth Edition
 };

 File &File::open(File::modes m)
 {
     mode |= READ;    // set the READ bit by default
     // other processing
     if (m & WRITE) // if opening READ and WRITE
     // processing to open the file in read/write mode
     return *this;
 }
```

What makes me wonder is: the `mode` member is just `2 bits`, so it can hold values: `0, 1, 2, 3` ( `00 01 10 11` in binary). The value `3` is defined as an enumeration that specifies the opening mode as `execute`, but if it is opened here for execute then it is opened too for writing: `3 & 2 = 2` `3 & 1 = 1`, which I think is a mistake. Normally each mode is independent from any other mode.

I mean, for example, in the member function `open()`, `mode |= READ` is OK to set the read bit, which is the first one. Now `if(m & WRITE)` looks meaningless if the user already has opened the file for Executing `3` (`11` in binary).

What do you think?

Comment: an enumeration is not necessarilt a bitfield.  This may be specifying an operation rather than permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mode` field is not being treated as a bitmask, and the `modes` type is not defining values in powers of 2. So you should not be using bitwise operations to set/query the `mode`, for exactly this reason that `EXECUTE` shares bits with `READ` and `WRITE`, which goes against your desire to have each mode be independent. In a proper bitmask, `EXECUTE` would be defined as `4` (`100` in binary), not `3`.

Comment: Yes thanks! that is what I wanted to say.